# How to Read a large avro file

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, avro, spark-avro

I am trying to read a large avro file (2GB) using spark-shell but I am getting stackoverflow error.

```
val newDataDF = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("abc.avro")
java.lang.StackOverflowError
  at com.databricks.spark.avro.SchemaConverters$.toSqlType(SchemaConverters.scala:71)
  at com.databricks.spark.avro.SchemaConverters$.toSqlType(SchemaConverters.scala:81)
```

I tried to increase driver memory and executor memory but I am still
getting same error.

```
./bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.1.0 --driver-memory 8G --executor-memory 8G
```

How can I read this file ? Is theere a way to partition this file?

Comment: That exception is related to schema/datatype conversion. So, increase memory won't help. Can you add full exception ?